# How can I access my localhost from my Android device

Tags: android, terminal, xampp, fedora, lampp

I am using `Linux Fedora`. I have `Xampp/Lampp` installed.

[image]

I have run `Xampp/Lampp` from terminal

```
sudo su 
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Output :

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 8.0.2-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

I am able to open localhost following ways on laptop.

```
http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/
http://localhost/
http://192.168.0.106/dashboard/
```

My ip is `192.168.0.106`

[image]

But, when I was trying to open it in Android Device it's not working..

[image]

What to do now? How can I access localhost from my Android Device?

I was reading the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779992/13146129) also. It's not helpful also..

[image]

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Should I edit anything?

[@Tenso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5747851/tenso)
[image]

```
>NAME=Fedora
>
>VERSION="33 (Workstation Edition)"
>
>ID=fedora
>
>VERSION_ID=33
```

Comment: You probably need to open port 80 on your linux machine, I think best tool for that would be ufw or you can use iptables if you're familiar with it.

Comment: @Tenso How to do that? I found this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands). I am sure that I have `iptables` installed cause, when I run `sudo iptables -S` I got output... So, what to do now?

Comment: Here is the tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04
But I don't know if ufw is available for fedora, maybe there is some other packet, that can help you with this

Comment: @Tenso I had run `sudo nano /etc/default/ufw`. ufw is completely null. There's no source code... I am installing ufw `sudo dnf install ufw`  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-debian-10

Comment: I found for fedora there is some other way to do this: 
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Security_Guide/sec-Open_Ports_in_the_firewall-CLI.html

Comment: @Tenso I have done something could you please see my edited question

Comment: @Tenso I tried [it](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Security_Guide/sec-Open_Ports_in_the_firewall-CLI.html) also. nothing is happening

Comment: Probably your server is bound to 127.0.0.1 or to that local ip. Dont bind to anything. And if you have too then bind to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: @blackapps I am not sure my server is bound to 127.0.0.1 or not? How to check that? In this question I earlier mentioned, I am able to run localhost by ip...

Comment: You should look in your server settings or its code. But if http://192.168.0.106/dashboard/ works then it is probably ok.

Comment: @blackapps I gave a picture of and code of `httpd.conf`

Comment: `But, when I was trying to open it in Android Device it's not working..` Your device can open nothing. You need to use an app. Which app are you using? Can you finally edit your post not talking about localhost but to the point?

Comment: @blackapps Isn't there way to visit the [page](https://192.168.0.106/dashboard/) in Android? When I was using Windows I was able to visit that [page](https://192.168.0.106/dashboard/)

Comment: Did you try a browser on your Android device?

Comment: @blackapps Yes! I gave a picture of it also..

Answer (score 0):

Don't different devices have different IP addresses? I've also sometimes tried `localhost` from Android, but it never seems to work. Just guessing that it can only be accessed from the device that it's hosted on.

Comment: I earlier had worked on Windows.... I could work with that... I had changes some codes from `Xampp`... Then, it was working when I was in Windows. But, it's my first time... I am trying to run localhost from Linux.. If you are using Windows I will suggest you to search on Google and YouTube how to solve your issue....

Comment: I don't need localhost I was just saying that it's never worked for me in any situations that I would start a localhost from another device.

Comment: Every device is its own localhost. So if a client tries to connect to localhost it tries to connect to a server on that same device. The same for 127.0.0.1